# Prove that if $y_0\neq0$ and also $\lvert y-y_0\rvert$ <$min(\frac{\lvert y_0\rvert}{2},\frac{\epsilon\lvert y_0\rvert^2}{2})$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Prove that if $y_0\neq0$ and also $\lvert y-y_0\rvert$ <$min(\frac{\lvert y_0\rvert}{2},\frac{\epsilon\lvert y_0\rvert^2}{2})$ then $y\neq0$ and also $\lvert  \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\rvert$<$\epsilon$

any ideas?

Comment: Is $\varepsilon$ pre-given or something else?

Comment: it is only a pre-given $\epsilon$>0

Answer (score 1):

$\lvert y-y_0\rvert < \frac{\lvert y_0\rvert}{2} \Rightarrow \lvert y\rvert > \frac{\lvert y_0\rvert}{2} > 0$

thus 
$$ y \neq 0$$
and
$$ \lvert  \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\rvert = \frac{\lvert y- y_0\rvert}{\lvert y\rvert\lvert y_0\rvert} < \frac{\frac{\epsilon\lvert y_0\rvert^2}{2}}{\frac{\lvert y_0\rvert}{2}\rvert\lvert y_0\rvert } = \epsilon.$$